# storing an array of string passed from Controller in ViewBag back to an array of string

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model in my project that contains appropriate code for fetching data from my database and it stores the data in DataTable object.

In the controller, I've extracted the data from DataTable in an array of string as follows

Controller:

```
DataTable infotable = new DataTable();
infotable = pfd.getProfileData(userid); //getProfileData is my method in model class
foreach (DataRow row in infotable.Rows) {

            studentinfo[0] = row["studentId"].ToString();
            studentinfo[1] = row["firstName"].ToString();
            studentinfo[2] = row["lastName"].ToString();
            studentinfo[3] = row["password"].ToString();
            studentinfo[4] = row["email"].ToString();
            studentinfo[5] = row["contactNo"].ToString();
            studentinfo[6] = (Convert.ToDateTime(row["regDate"])).ToShortDateString();
        }
        ViewData["studentinfo"] = studentinfo;
        return View();
```

In the view the code that I've used to display the data is ViewBag goes like:

```
 @foreach (string info in ViewData["studentinfo"] as string[])
 {
      <p>@info</p>    
 }
```

This set of code works perfectly fine and shows the required output.

Now I want the data in the ViewBag back in an array of String.

Or possibly I can pass the String itself to the view from controller, if so how can I access the passed string array in View?

Comment: i think if you need to access the data furthermore, the easiest way would be to put it into the session. Storing the datatable into the session: Session["infotable"]=infotable; To get the data from the session use : DataTable info = (DataTable)Session["infotable"];

Comment: Please Explain - "Now I what the data in the ViewBag back in an array of String"

Comment: @user1519979 this seems legitimate. And then I access the DataTable in the usual way as I've already done, right?

Comment: @Typist Editted that 'what' to 'want'

Comment: right, just cast the object of the session to use it on the usual way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already accessing the passed string array in the view. `ViewData["studentinfo"` is your string array. Though, what I suspect you want to do is use a typed view. Here's what I suggest:

First make a model type for student info (maybe named StudentInfo), something like this:

```
public class StudentInfo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
}
```

Then, change you code where you apply the array to this:

```
var studentinfo = new StudentInfo();
foreach (DataRow row in infotable.Rows) {

    studentinfo.Id = row["studentId"].ToString();
    studentinfo.FirstName = row["firstName"].ToString();
    ....
    ....
}
return View(studentinfo);
```

Then, in your view, add this at the top

```
@model StudentInfo // might need to include full namespace
```

And to print out the values you do

```
@Model.FirstName
```

Now, if you still want to send it as an array, you still can, simply change the view `@model StudentInfo` to `@model string[]` and pass in your array to `View` in the controller, then you can treat `Model` as a string array in the view.

Comment: I've already made an instance of my class profileData(here mentioned by you as StudentInfo) in the Controller. Is it necessary that i use var studentInfo = new StudentInfo(); instead of Studentinfo si = new StudentInfo(); ?

Comment: If you already have an instance, then just use that instance. Also, `var a = new B()` is the same as `B a = new B()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this in View

```
@model string []
```

and in controller pass your  string array

```
 return View(studentinfo);
```

Now use like this

```
 @foreach (string info in Model)
 {
    <p>
       @info
    </p>    
 }
```

Comment: can you show me some proper code. I'm not understanding it.